# Какое условие прописать, чтобы не выводить таблицу без записей

Tags: php

Добрый день всем подскажите как решить данную небольшую проблемку. Есть многомерный массив который содержит себе категории, и предметы которые относятся к этой категории,и есть скрипт который на основе этого массива генерирует таблицу. Мне нужно написать условие которые не будет выводить таблицу в категории которой нет предметов. Пробовал проверять на переменную **$total** но не получилось. Привожу пример кода и структуру массива чтобы было понятно о чем речь!

```
Array
(
    [(ТН) Неодеваемый - EF] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Великолепная ряса
                    [color] => #884EA2
                    [title] => EF
                    [category] => (ТН) Неодеваемый - EF
                    [important] => 0
                    [quantity] => 2
                )
    )
)
foreach($categories as $cat =>$things){
        $number = 0;
        $total = 0;

        echo "<table align='center' class='info'>";
        echo "<tr>
                <th colspan='3'>$cat</th>
              </tr>";

        foreach($things as $thing){
            $total+=$thing['quantity'];

            if($thing['important']==1){
                $style = "background-color:#AA5F82;color:#FFFFFF;";
            }
            else{
                $style = "";
            }

            if($thing['quantity']!=0){
                $number++;

                echo "<tr>
                        <td align='center' width='30'>$number</td>
                        <td style='color:$thing[color]' class='info_align'><b>$thing[name]</b>
                        <small><span style='background-color:$thing[color];color:#FFFFFF'><b>&nbsp;$thing[title]&nbsp;</b></span></small></td>
                        <td align='center' width='30' style=$style>$thing[quantity]</td>
                     </tr>";
            }
        }
            echo "<tr align='center' style='color:#A01B1B'>
                    <td colspan='2' ><b>Всего</b></td>
                    <td align='center' width='30'><b>$total</b></td>
                 </tr>";      
            echo "</table></br>";
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это точно вы писали код этого цикла? Если да, то выглядит очень странно, что не догадались перед

```
echo "<table align='center' class='info'>";
```

поставить простую проверку вида

```
if (count($things)) {
    echo "<table align='center' class='info'>";
    ...
    echo "</table></br>";
}
```

Comment: Наврное я не правильно объяснил проблему,извиняюсь.Вообщем из формы я получаю поток данных который сверяю с базой данных,если в данном поток есть такая вещь и не одна то их кол-во и записывается в ячейку [quantity],так что массив пустым не может быть,просто если нет совпадений quantity = 0

Comment: Тогда я бы на вашем месте сначала получил массив из элементов, которые нужно вывести. Можно складывать в него только id, а можно полностью копировать данные, если элементов не так много.

Кстати, это разумнее всего сделать в том месте, где происходит заполнение ``quantity``

Comment: Ага понял спасибо

Comment: Добавил как вы и подсказали и все отлично работает!

    if($quantity!=0){
       $categories[$result['category']][] = $result;
    }